# How to set text of Button as ON and OFF on each click in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, logic

I am working on winform application. i have one `button` and its default text is `ON`. now when I click on button, its text should be changed to `OFF` an if i again click the button. is text should be changed back to `ON` . i have no idea how to do so i used `counter` logic. but i am not sure in it and not comfortable withit.

one more thing. if text is `ON` then employee can receive notification. so `accept_notf = 1` and if text is `OFF` employee can not receive notification. so `accept_notf =0`

i have tried this.:

```
private void btnNotification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        if (btn.Text == "ON")
        {
            accept_notif = "1";
            btn.Text = "OFF";
        }
        else  (btn.Text == "OFF")
        {
            accept_notif = "0";
            btn.Text = "ON";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: what purpose does that loop achieve? Can you explain the code you wrote?

Comment: i am trying that, if odd count then text will be "OFF" . any other idea sir?

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default text to "ON", When the button is clicked if the text is "ON" set it to "OFF" else set it to "ON"

```
private void btnNotification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
        if (btn.Text == "ON")
        {
            btn.Text = "OFF";
            accept_notif = "0";
        }
        else if (btn.Text == "OFF")
        {
            btn.Text = "ON";
            accept_notif = "1";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working. i have edited my question sir. and additional portion is not working

Comment: Why is the else if necessary? Wouldn't a simple else be enough?

Comment: @Mitulátbáti because it must be switched between "ON" and "OFF" if somewhere else in code set it to something else it should not overwrite that value.

Comment: One liner, for those that care: btnNotification.Text = btnNotification.Text == "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. First, in our event handler we get our button instance from event arguments and Downcast it back to Button type. Then we use conditional operator to find out is it set to "ON" and if it's so we set it to "OFF" otherwise (operator ':') we set it to "ON"

```
private void btnNotification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null) return;       
    button.Text = button.Text == "ON"? "OFF" : "ON";
    accept_notf = button.Text == "ON"? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: this is a code only answer, try add some explanation to it. try change "On" to "ON"

Comment: It's almost the same question ... Just added a line and updated again

Comment: `btn` not in current context. some changes are required sir. otherwise code is cool.

Comment: Tell me please what is not covered ? What do you mean by 'not in current context' ?

Comment: just remove `btn.Text`

Comment: Oh sorry for this little typo... Edited and now it seems ok

Answer (score -1):

In your click handler method you should examine if the text of your button is "ON" or "OFF" (because the changes depend on this).

For example like this:

```
if ((sender as Button).Text == "ON")
    (sender as Button).Text = "OFF";
else
    (sender as Button).Text = "ON";

...
or you can create a variable and work with that:
Button tmpButton = (sender as Button);
```

or you can use directly the *button* itself for accessing its text (I prefer this way when there is only 1 button).

```
if (btnStatusIndicator.Text == "ON")
{
    btnStatusIndicator.Text = "OFF";
    acceptNotif = 0; // learn camelCase when you write C# code! :)
}
else
{
    btnStatusIndicator.Text = "ON";
    acceptNotif = 1;
}
```

and if the program allows more values than just ON or OFF, you can use **switch** statement to determine the text (with this you can prepare your program to deal with other situations, when the text is not either ON or OFF).

```
switch (btnStatusIndicator.Text)
{
    case "OFF": ... break;
    case "ON": ... break;
    case "your other value": ... break;
    case "your other value": ... break;
    case "your other value": ... break;
    default: ... break;
}
```

Comment: what if `sender as Button` becomes `null`?

Comment: An exception, sir. But that's not gonna happen ;)

Comment: if you assign this function to a `Label` click event then there will.

Comment: And you are trying to cast an object to `Button` three times. You can do that only once

Comment: Well don't assign the function to a Label... we're talking about a button's event handler where the sender definitely will be a Button. Your second comment: That's true. But that wouldn't change anything...